# $\mathbf{R^8}$ as direct sum of $U$ and $W$.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces

Is the following Proof Correct?

**Theorem.** Given that $U$ and $W$ are subspaces of $V$ such that $\dim U=3$, and $\dim W=5$ such that $U+W=\mathbf{R^8}$, Then $\mathbf{R^8}=U\oplus W$.

**Proof.** It is not difficult to see that the following list forms a bases for $\mathbf{R^8}$.
$$(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0),...,(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1)$$
therefore $\dim\mathbf{R^8}=8$ and making use of $\mathbf{2.43}$ we have the following equation
$$\dim(\mathbf{R^8})=\dim(U)+\dim(W)-\dim(U\cap W)\tag{1}$$
thus
$$\dim(U\cap W)=3+5-8=0\tag{2}$$
the equation above implies that $U\cap W=\{0\}$ consequently 
$\mathbf{R^8}=U+W=U\oplus W$.

$\blacksquare$

Comment: Seems right to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct, but if you want to be technically explicit you need to mention that U+W is a subspace of R, provided that U,W are. So, you have the subspace U+W of R, which has equal dimension, thus from a known corrollary R=U+W. Your proof about the triviality of their intersection is correct.